# CakePHP - How to connect to docker's db container by using socket in CakePHP project

Tags: php, cakephp, docker

I'm trying to use to develop my web application by using docker instead of MAMP. And this is my first time to do the job. After doing a lot of search. I finally be able to link to my db container and see standard CakePHP default page with all green.

But when I tried to use CakePHP's bake function below.

```
bin/cake bake all users
```

I got the error below.

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in [CakePhpProjects/cakephptest/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php, line 48]
```

But the same function is working when I used the environment of MAMP and added the following code in the place of "DataResource" of config/app.php.

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

So is any way to solve this problem?

My DockerFile is this.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
&&  apt-get install -y \
        composer \
        curl \
        php \
        php-intl \
        php-mbstring \
        php-mysql \
        unzip \
        zip
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
```

And my docker-compose.yml file is this

```
version: '2'
services:
        db:
                image: mysql
                environment:
                        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
                        - MYSQL_DATABASE=cakephptest
                        - MYSQL_USER=root
                        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
        web:
                build: .
                command: cakephptest/bin/cake server -H 0.0.0.0
                volumes:
                        - .:/code
                ports:
                        - "8765:8765"
                depends_on:
                        - db
                links:
                        - db

        phpmyadmin:
                image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
                environment:
                        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
                        - PMA_HOST=db
                        - PMA_USER=root
                        - PMA_PASSWORD=root
                links:
                        - db
                ports:
                        - 8080:80
                volumes:
                         - /sessions
```

My CakePHP's DB setting is this

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            /**
             * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
             * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
             * the following line and set the port accordingly
             */
            //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'database' => 'caketest',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,

            /**
             * Set identifier quoting to true if you are using reserved words or
             * special characters in your table or column names. Enabling this
             * setting will result in queries built using the Query Builder having
             * identifiers quoted when creating SQL. It should be noted that this
             * decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and
             * manipulated before being executed.
             */
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

            /**
             * During development, if using MySQL < 5.6, uncommenting the
             * following line could boost the speed at which schema metadata is
             * fetched from the database. It can also be set directly with the
             * mysql configuration directive 'innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'
             * which is the recommended value in production environments
             */
            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],

            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
            'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the docker container hostname and not localhost:

```
'host' => 'db'
```